# how to set column to straight down like this?

Tags: c, row

I tried to do a numeric puzzle and I want a column to set of like this

```
\ ----- ----- ----- -----
|  10 |  1  |  6  |  7  |
\ ----- ----- ----- -----
|  4  |  14 |  3  |  9  |
\ ----- ----- ----- -----
|  2  |  11 |  5  |     |
\ ----- ----- ----- -----
|  15 |  8  |  12 |  13 |
\ ----- ----- ----- -----
```

I tried to do this by using this code

```
    printf("\\ ----- ----- ----- -----\n");
    printf("|  %2.1d |  %2.1d |  %2.1d |  %2.1d |\n",a[0][0],a[0][1],a[0][2],a[0][3]);
    printf("\\ ----- ----- ----- -----\n");
    printf("|  %2.1d |  %2.1d |  %2.1d |  %2.1d |\n",a[1][0],a[1][1],a[1][2],a[1][3]);
    printf("\\ ----- ----- ----- -----\n");
    printf("|  %2.1d |  %2.1d |  %2.1d |  %2.1d |\n",a[2][0],a[2][1],a[2][2],a[2][3]);
    printf("\\ ----- ----- ----- -----\n");
    printf("|  %2.1d |  %2.1d |  %2.1d |  %2.1d |\n",a[3][0],a[3][1],a[3][2],a[3][3]);
    printf("\\ ----- ----- ----- -----");
```

It turn out to be like this

```
\ ----- ----- ----- -----
|   6 |  14 |  13 |  10 |
\ ----- ----- ----- -----
|   3 |   0 |   4 |   9 |
\ ----- ----- ----- -----
|   2 |   5 |  11 |   7 |
\ ----- ----- ----- -----
|   8 |  15 |  12 |   1 |
\ ----- ----- ----- -----
```

How can I fixed this. It's seems to work only with 10-15.

Comment: You want to print nothing if the value is zero?

Comment: @DanielKleinstein. yes. and if you looking at example and my output. It's seems like number work like "06" than "6" so the column is not straight down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From documentation on [`*printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

In general:

> . followed by integer number or *, or neither that specifies *precision* of the conversion.

And for `%d`:

> Precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear. The default precision is 1. If both the converted value and the precision are ​0​ the conversion results in no characters.

The specifier to use is either `"%-2.0d"` or `%2.0d`, depending on if you want the number left- or right-justified, respectively.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Left-justified:\n");
    printf("| %-2.0d |\n", 6);
    printf("| %-2.0d |\n", 11);
    printf("| %-2.0d |\n", 0);

    printf("Right-justified:\n");
    printf("| %2.0d |\n", 3);
    printf("| %2.0d |\n", 14);
    printf("| %2.0d |\n", 0);
}
```

Output:

```
Left-justified:
| 6  |
| 11 |
|    |
Right-justified:
|  3 |
| 14 |
|    |
```

---

A note about the precision specifier:

> If neither a number nor * is used, the precision is taken as zero.

This means the form of `"%-2.d"` would also work.